# String, Pattern match

Tags: java, android

I can build the string like this:

```
String str = "Phone number %s just texted about property %s";
String.format(str, "(714) 321-2620", "690 Warwick Avenue (679871)");

//Output: Phone number (714) 321-2620 just texted about property 690 Warwick Avenue (679871)
```

What I want to achieve is reverse of this. Input will be following string

*Phone number (714) 321-2620 just texted about property 690 Warwick Avenue (679871)*

And I want to retrieve, "*(714) 321-2620*" & "*690 Warwick Avenue (679871)*" from input

Can any one please give pointer, how to achieve this in Java or Android?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Drop *Phone number* and *just texted about property*. Then cut the new string into two pieces. And you will get what you need. Here is [`String` in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
String input = "Phone number (714) 321-2620 just texted about property 690 Warwick Avenue (679871)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^Phone number (.*) just texted about property (.*)$").matcher(input);
if(m.find()) {
  String first = m.group(1); // (714) 321-2620
  String second = m.group(2); // 690 Warwick Avenue (679871)
  // use the two values
}
```

Complete working code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    String input = "Phone number (714) 321-2620 just texted about property 690 Warwick Avenue (679871)";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^Phone number (.*) just texted about property (.*)$").matcher(input);
    if(m.find()) {
      String first = m.group(1); // (714) 321-2620
      String second = m.group(2); // 690 Warwick Avenue (679871)
      System.out.println(first);
      System.out.println(second);
  }
}
```

And the link on [ideone](http://ideone.com/eJb3l4).

Comment: hi,can someone explain it?

Comment: @MehulJoisar it is pretty simple - `^` stands for the beginning of the string you are matching `$` - for the end. So you only care about a match that matches the whole string. The `(.*)` are match groups and they will match any sequence of symbols. `m.group(1)` will return the first such group and `group(1)` - the second one. The remaining symbols in the match string simply match one to one to the characters in the string you are matching. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: @lvaylo: Yes,Thanks.it's totally clear now except just one little thing.what is the need of m.find() ?

Comment: @MehulJoisar from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()): `Resets this matcher and then attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern, starting at the specified index.` So it effectively does two things - first it checks if we match the string and second does the actual matching thus you can obtain the match groups using `m.group(<number>)`

Comment: @lvaylo:Got it completely.I'm glad to learn this concept.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, and at the same time pretty hard.

Basically, you can easily just use String.split() to split up the string in parts on regular expressions or first appearances of characters.

You will however, need to have a clear pattern to detect in which the phone number and the address are. This depends on your own definition of the possibilities of these info's.